# iptables ssh configuration for specific ip - can't establish connection

Tags: iptables

For practising purposes, i'm attempting to establish a SSH connection to a Kali virtual machine with an iptables firewall configured to permit only specific SSH connections. Initially, i successfully connected by allowing all incoming SSH connections. However, upon modifying the /etc/iptables/rules.v4 file to restrict connections to only my host IP, i got a 'Connection timed out' error. What am i missing? I am aware that there already are simular posts; i tried to apply the answers i found there but to no avail.

```
:INPUT DROP [22:1320]
:FORWARD DROP [0:0]
:OUTPUT DROP [91:7403]
-A INPUT -i lo -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -m conntrack --ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p icmp -m icmp --icmp-type 8 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -s 192.168.178.45/32 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 22 -m conntrack --ctstate NEW,EST>
-A OUTPUT -o lo -j ACCEPT
-A OUTPUT -m conntrack --ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
-A OUTPUT -p icmp -m icmp --icmp-type 8 -j ACCEPT
-A OUTPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 80 -j ACCEPT
-A OUTPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 443 -j ACCEPT
-A OUTPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 53 -j ACCEPT
-A OUTPUT -p udp -m udp --dport 53 -j ACCEPT
-A OUTPUT -p tcp -m tcp --sport 22 -m conntrack --ctstate ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
COMMIT
```

Answer (score 1):

I found my own answer. Instead of my wlp3s0 ip i needed to use my virbr0 ip